# UITableView inside UIScrollView - Cell not clickable

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, swift2

I have a problem with a UITableView not detecting touches.

In an iPhone-only app, I have a UIViewController, which containts:

- UIScrollView

  - UIView (let's say a content view)

    - Some labels
    - UITableView (last)

The labels have a dynamic height, because they contain some text that I must retrive from the web, so I'm using auto layout.
I'm setting the content size of the UIScrollView inside the  `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method, and I'm doing this by summing `UITableView.frame.origin.y` and its height.

Here comes the problem: when the labels contain only some words and the UITableView does not exceed the iPhone screen size, everything works ok. But when they grow, and the UITableView gets pushed down, when I scroll down I can't click on the cell anymore. Also, if when loading the view the table is half visible and half not, I can click the visible cells, but if I scroll down, I can't click the others.

I'm using swift 2 and Xcode 7.

Here is an example:

**Clickable:**

[image]

**Unclickable:**

[image]

Comment: does it click when you long press on cell?

Comment: No, it does not respond at all.

Comment: Are you using `AutoLayout`?

Comment: Duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538125/uitableview-inside-uiscrollview-table-cell-is-not-selectable?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the following thing:

```
yourView.clipToBounds = true
```

Now, if `UITableView` does not appears means your `UIView` is not same bigger to hold down `UITableView`.

Make sure that your `UIView` height is bigger to hold the contents in it and then try to tap on it.

> Updated:

If you are using `AutoLayout`, then do the following thing.

1. Give the fix height to `UIView`
2. Take the outlet of height constraint of `UIView`
3. Now, in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` change the constraint of `UIView` to `UITableView` `contentSize` height.

   self.heightConstraint = self.tableView.contentSize.height

Let me know, if this helps!

Comment: Ok, that's making things a bit clearer. Now the `UITableCell` does not appear.
But, in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method, I'm setting `self.contentView.frame.size.height = self.answerTable.frame.origin.y + self.answerTable.frame.size.height`, which should set the `ContentView` higher enough. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout

Comment: Yes I'm using AutoLayout

Comment: Fantastic. I didn't set the constraint to what you said, but editing the constraint instead of using `frame.size...` worked. Thank you so so so much!

Comment: @SohilR.Memon you helped me a lot! +1 to your comment!

Answer (score 0):

Adding some info to the [@Rémy Virin's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21677268/uitableview-inside-uiscrollview-not-receiving-first-tap-after-scrollling) answer here:

From Apple Documentation, you shouldn't embed a UITableViewinside a UIScrollView.

> Important: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.

**Addition:*Solution*** Since you want to scroll the content above table also, the one solution is place a `Header View` for the Table and place the Content over there to make it Scroll along the Table View.

Comment: So I should take the table outside the content view, and set `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = myContentView`? But isn't the table still inside the scrollview, or should I remove it as well? And, if yes, would the table automatically scroll the header view? Thanks.

Comment: Just drag an drop an UIView just above the table view...the View will automatically become an Header View of the table. there you can place the contents.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Autolayout`, no need to specify `contentSize` to `UIScrollView` as it will automatically expand by taking the height of its subview.

In your case, increase the height of the Base `UIView` (content view as mentioned by you) which holds the `tableView` when the `tableView height` increases.

`UITableView` becomes unresponsive when it extends below its container view.

Comment: I decided to manually specify `contentSize` because I couldn't make the scrollview work properly with auto layout.
Is it possible to set an auto layout constraint to extend the `UIView` based on the `tableview height`?
EDIT. Here is the code i use:
`contentView.frame.size.height = self.answerTable.frame.origin.y + self.answerTable.frame.size.height
scrollView.contentSize.height = self.answerTable.frame.origin.y + self.answerTable.frame.size.height`.

Is it right?

Comment: Try this method:
init(item:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:)

Comment: For the view in the screenshots you showed, UITableView itself will do the stuff. 
You can create this by using custom sectionHeaders and tableViewCells

Comment: I don't understand, what should I init with this method?